# HealthCare Finder API Version 2 and 3 Functionality Differences

Tags: api, healthcare-finder-api

Our application currently point to http://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v2.0/. This website no longer working. Looks like there is a new URL available https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0.

Where can we find the functionality changes between the 2 versions? Is there any documentation that can help us to quickly do the analysis?

Comment: for the record, this forum is independent from Healthare.gov, although [questions are directed](http://i.imgur.com/cDdIoFt.jpg) here. for your question, you may find contacting Healthcare.gov directly is more useful.

Comment: I closed this question as "off-topic" because it's not about open data, and instead about the functionality difference of a specific gov't API that redirects users here.